# How to achieve Stack like animation with user click event in React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, react-spring

I want to animate my component like below (showing up new Container from bottom and `Stack` on the previous container) when user click the `button`.

[image: Image from Gyazo]

After researching few libraries, I noticed [React Spring](https://codesandbox.io/embed/j0y0vpz59) might be a good way to achieve `Stack` component and animation, but I haven't used this library so not sure if this is the best way.

I currently have simple component like below with a clickable button - what is the best way to achieve `Stack` like animation?
I am using React/Typescript, ReactHooks and Tailwind CSS.

```
export const HomeLaunchShop: FC = () => {
    <div>
                    <form>
                        <div>
                            <a>This is first container</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input
                                className={s.input}
                                name="phone"
                                type="tel"
                                maxLength={13}
                                value="xxx-xxxx-xxxx"
                                readOnly
                            />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Button
                        title={'Try Payment'}
                        onClick={() => {}}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
}
```